# Invalid hook call - useContext - React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting an error invalid hooks call when I am using useContext in function. Please find below code. and suggest solution .

```
import React from 'react';
import { AddlistContext } from '@contexts';

const asyncCall = (value) => {
  const context = React.useContext(AddlistContext);
  console.log(value, context);
  return '';
};
```

[Here is the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-field-z0s8d?file=/src/App.js)
Using context in validation.js

Please I need help desperately.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried `useAsyncCall`? Pretty sure it's just your linter. If not, is where you're calling. Remember a hook should only be called from inside a component's lifecycle

Comment: You can only use hooks in react function components or other hooks. This is just a function, so it would not work. Either transform it to a component or useAsyncCall from a function compoennt.

Comment: Hooks are just functions... Components too

Comment: Yes but they need the react context => so they have to be called in a hook or function component.

Comment: Exactly my point. There is nothing wrong with this code so probably a linter issue (if it's just a warning) or where it's being called

Comment: @Dupocas. Its not linter issue . "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. "

Comment: How /where are you calling the function?

Comment: @Stuck . This I am calling on react-hook-form  validate

Comment: That is probably the issue and people cannot help you without seeing the code. You can only use the shown function from a component or another hook but the validation probably is conditional or triggered by an event or so..

Comment: <TextField
 name="title"
 rules={{
   validate: (value) => asyncCall(value)
 }}
/> @Stuck here is the code

Comment: Hi Folks , I have updated code in sandbox . for better understanding

Comment: `import React, {useContext} from 'react'`,
`const context = useContext(AddlistContext);`
Try to change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ValueRequired is not a component, or at least you're not using it as a component. At the moment, you are calling it as a plain function.

I know that there is a lot of confusion between a function and a react functional component as the latter seems to be simply a function. To create a component, the first thing you need is a named function, an anonymous function cannot be a component, with a capital first letter ([doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component)). But most importantly, you need to call it in a way that make React render it, otherwise there is no way you can us React functionality like hooks or context.

For ValueRequired to not throw an error, you need to call it like this:

```
// Somewhere in you're render function
<ValueRequired />
```

But that won't solve your problem. In your case, I think you should use the hook pattern as they can access the context:

1. Create a useValueRequired function
2. Call it in your app or the component that manage your form

Try something like this:

```
const useValueRequired = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(AddlistContext);

    isRequired = value => {
        if (!value) {
            return "value is required";
        }
    }
    
    return {
        isRequired,
    };
}

const App = () => {
    // ...
    const { isRequired } = useValueRequired();
   
    // ...
    <Controller
        render={(props) => {
            return (
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="name"
                    fullWidth
                    {...props}
                    error={errors?.name}
                    helperText={errors?.name?.message}
                />
            );
        }}
        control={control}
        name="name"
        rules={{ validate: isRequired }}
    />

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Joessel: Its seems to work for one method .How can I pass multiple validation methods using above solution?.

Comment: Thanks @P.E. Joessel.The above solution is working perfectly as per my requirement